# Difference beteween Threads in OS and threads in programming languages

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, java-threads

I am learning user level threads and kernel level threads. I wonder what the mapping is between these OS threads and the Threads that programmers write using programming languages like JAVA, Python using some thread library. How are these mapped/related. I am new to this topic, sorry if it is silly.

Comment: java created thread will run in `JVM` and `JVM` will run in OS or CPU

Answer (score 0):

User level threads are faster in terms of context switching since they are typically in same operating system process(or may be thread). User level threading like in higher level languages makes kernel level threading model simpler and they require very minimal threading support at kernel level. They are faster and much better in performance.

Kernel level threading is expensive because of context switching overhead. The synchronization and sharing resources among threads are still less expensive than multiple-process model, but more expensive than user-level threads.

Typically in modern days there are hybrid threading used with an intent of gaining from both user level as well as system level threading.